# C# ... Connect to iPhone via USB/iTunes - possible?

Tags: c#, iphone, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0, itunes-sdk

Does anyone know if it is possible to read/edit an iPhone's contact list using `C#`, assuming offcourse that the iPhone is plugged in into a Windows PC via USB cable/iTunes?

Answer (score 0):

You can use CFManzana / Manaza or MobileDevice dll for the connection of iPhone. below is an example how you can do that.

```
// this variable will be declared in your class .

public static string devicename;

CFManzana.iDevice
phone = New iDevice();
phone.connect += phone_connect;

void phone_connect(object sender, ConnectEventArgs args)
        {
// here your will add your exception handling details.
           }

// now extract your device details.

devicename = phone.getDeviceName or phone.CopyValue("DeviceName"); \\it all depends what version of Manzana you have downloaded.

//now assign the value to the field 

this.txtname.text = devicename;
```

---

Answer (score 0):

If you want to connect to an iOS device over USB from Windows, you can try the imobiledevice-net NuGet package, which I maintain. For example, to list all iOS devices which are currently connected to your PC, you could do this:

```
ReadOnlyCollection<string> udids;
int count = 0;

var idevice = LibiMobileDevice.Instance.iDevice;
var lockdown = LibiMobileDevice.Instance.Lockdown;

var ret = idevice.idevice_get_device_list(out udids, ref count);

if (ret == iDeviceError.NoDevice)
{
    // Not actually an error in our case
    return;
}

ret.ThrowOnError();

// Get the device name
foreach (var udid in udids)
{
    iDeviceHandle deviceHandle;
    idevice.idevice_new(out deviceHandle, udid).ThrowOnError();

    LockdownClientHandle lockdownHandle;
    lockdown.lockdownd_client_new_with_handshake(deviceHandle, out lockdownHandle, "Quamotion").ThrowOnError();

    string deviceName;
    lockdown.lockdownd_get_device_name(lockdownHandle, out deviceName).ThrowOnError();

    deviceHandle.Dispose();
    lockdownHandle.Dispose();
}
```